# Find duplicate excel value based on multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have a spreadsheet that has 4 columns (see below for example). The first column has a unique ID, and then the next three are date requested, Customer name, and Country. I want to figure out how to match IDs when the other three columns are the same.

Current Data Set:

```
ID | Date Requested | Customer name | Country
1      1/1/2019         Bob Smith      USA
2      2/2/2019         Sal Jones      DE
3      1/1/2019         Bob Smith      USA
4      12/2/2017        Jim Gold       USA
5      2/2/2019         Sal Jones      DE
```

I want to be able to create another column that would show the ID of row that has the same information. For example, the new table would look like:

```
ID | Date Requested | Customer name | Country | Duplicate ID
1      1/1/2019         Bob Smith      USA         3
2      2/2/2019         Sal Jones      DE          5
3      1/1/2019         Bob Smith      USA         1
4      12/2/2017        Jim Gold       USA
5      2/2/2019         Sal Jones      DE          2
```

Is there a way to use VLookUp for the new column or some other function in excel?

EDIT: The end goal is to be able to actually link the two together with a common 'Group' or ID' number. For example, the table would look like this in the end:

```
ID | Date Requested | Customer name | Country | Duplicate ID | Group
1      1/1/2019         Bob Smith      USA         3            1
2      2/2/2019         Sal Jones      DE          5            2
3      1/1/2019         Bob Smith      USA         1            1
4      12/2/2017        Jim Gold       USA
5      2/2/2019         Sal Jones      DE          2            2
```

This way, you could filter the Group Column and the two duplicate entries would be next to each other/have a common link in the same column.

Comment: Can there be multiple duplicates, or always just one? Are your IDs purely numeric, or alphanumeric?

Comment: Do you have a *next step*? or is this the final result?  If you are trying to do something other than just an audit entry, there might be a better method of obtaining your final desired result.

Comment: will there always be only one duplicate or could be more than one duplicates? and what is your ultimate goal after finding the ID of duplicated entries? deleting them?

Comment: There will always be only one duplicate or no duplicates

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option:

[image]

Formula in `E2`:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(1,INDEX(($B$2:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B))=B2)*($C$2:INDEX(C:C,COUNTA(C:C))=C2)*(($D$2:INDEX(D:D,COUNTA(D:D))=D2))*(ROW($A$2:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A)))<>ROW()),),0),"")
```

In case your `ID` do not match the `MATCH` =).... you'll need to implement another `INDEX`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A)),MATCH(1,INDEX(($B$2:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B))=B2)*($C$2:INDEX(C:C,COUNTA(C:C))=C2)*(($D$2:INDEX(D:D,COUNTA(D:D))=D2))*(ROW($A$2:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A)))<>ROW()),),0)),"")
```

It's a bit extensive, but I wanted to make it dynamic for you to avoid using whole column references and thus speed up your formula. ***Speed > Length***

While it's an array formula, don't worry to enter it as such. The `INDEX` after the `MATCH` function catches the results into an array.